# query find ranking with criteria in mysql

Tags: mysql

i have a data in table like this:

```
======================================= 
class |  name  |  study  |  avg scores
======================================= 
1      alfa       c#          75
1      alfa       php         70
1      beta       c#          80
1      beta       php         90
2      carlie     c#          70
2      carlie     php         70
2      delta      c#          90
2      delta      php         90
```

and i want the result like this :

```
========================================== 
rangking |   class    |   name   | average
========================================== 
1             1           beta       85
2             1           alfa       72.5
1             2           delta      90
2             2           carlie     70
```

criteria rangking 1 = average > 80

criteria rangking 2 = average > 65 and < 80

so how to make a query in mysql to get those results?

please help me, I've tried many times but have not been successful

Thanks

Comment: What is the ranking if the average is exactly = `80`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT CASE WHEN average > 80 THEN 1
            WHEN average > 65 THEN 2
       END AS rangking,
       class, name, average
FROM (SELECT class, name, AVG(avg_scores) AS average
      FROM YourTable
      GROUP BY class, name
      HAVING average > 65) AS subquery
ORDER BY class, rangking
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
SELECT CASE
           WHEN avg(average) >80 THEN 1
           WHEN avg(average)>65
                AND avg(average)<80 THEN 2
       END AS `ranking`,
       CLASS, name, avg(average) AS average
FROM TABLE_NAME
GROUP BY CLASS, name;
```